Powershell script to uninstall a software when running via SCCM does not identify the registry keys of that software
I'm trying to uninstall a software using this code
$path = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{Product-cod-1}"

function Uninstall_SW {
    Write-Host "Starting Uninstallation.."
    if(Test-Path $path) {
        $uninstallStr = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $path).UninstallString
        if($uninstallStr) {
            Write-Host "Uninstalling SW command: $uninstallStr"
            Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" ArgumentList "/c $uninstallStr /qn" -Wait -NoNewWindow
            Write-Host "Uninstall Complete"
        } else {
                Write-Host "No uninstall str found"
        } else {
               Write-Host "Registry Path not found $path"
        }
    }

}

Unistall_SW

Now this work perfectly fine when I run locally on my laptop. But when this is deployed to Microsoft SCCM and on running this script in Software center, it fails to uninstall the software as it does not find the Registry Path and I have confirmed that the registry path is correct.
is there something I'm missing?
Note: Also tried with uninstall using get-package and uninstall package, but that does not work either

If the SCCM client is 32-bit, then if it looks for HKLM\SOFTWARE Windows will automatically redirect it to HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node due to registry redirection.

Uninstall-package only works for msi installs.  If it's installed as one user, the system user won't see it.

Even though the SCCM client is 64Bit, Bill_Stewart is probably still on the right track, because all legacy programs are executed as 32bit Processes. So if you use an application make sure the 64bit checkbox is checked, if it is indeed a programm fix this by not calling powershell.exe but C:\Windows\sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe in your program which will force windows to use a 64bit powershell scripting host. (the folder sysnative does not exist that is a hardlink or something that is only created for 32bit processes but you can test it, it will work)
